# Sorting Floating Point Numbers In MIPS

Tags: sorting, floating-point, mips

We are given a project in which we have to find the min, max, and median of entered floating point numbers in MIPS. I'm currently trying to sort the numbers in ascending order but am not having much luck. I'm stuck on an error that says address out of range. Here is my code, can anyone help?

```
.data
 arr: .word 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0,0
 end: .float 0.0
 low: .float 0

pro:  .asciiz "This Program will show the max, min,\nand median of the entered values.\nType 0.0 to end the program."
pro1: .asciiz "\nEnter a floating point value.\n"        

.text
li $v0, 4
la $a0, pro
syscall

index:
li   $s0,  0
li   $t0,  0
lwc1 $f11, end

main:
li $v0, 4
la $a0, pro1
syscall
li $v0, 6
syscall
la     $s0, arr
sw     $v0, arr
add    $s0, $s0, 4
c.eq.s $f0, $f11

loop1:
swc1   $f0, arr($s0)
addi   $s0, $s0, 4
swc1   $f1, arr($s0)
c.lt.s $f0, $f1
bc1t   min
j      main

min:
swc1 $f0, low
j    main

li $v0, 2
syscall

exit:
lwc1 $f12, low
li   $v0,  2
syscall
li   $v0, 10
syscall
```

Comment: Where does this error occur, and what *specifically* does it say?

Comment: line 32: runtime exception at 0x00400058: address out of range 0x20020004

Comment: And which is line 32?

Comment: swc1 $f0, arr($s0). First line after loop 1

Answer (score 1):

You are loading the address of `arr` into `$s0`, but then using `$s0` as an offset from `arr` (`arr($s0)`).  If `$s0` has the address of the data you want, just use `($s0)`.